# refresh MATERIALIZED VIEW monthly

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

if I want to refresh it **monthly** how to do that ?

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW <view-name>;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW <view-name> 
refresh on demand 
start with sysdate next sysdate + 30
as select
```

also use `refresh on demand`  ??? or not

Comment: Use cronjob where you can set a time when it will refreshed. Also You can refresh it anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clause `start with...next` of the materialized view with either refresh complete or on demand.

```
SQL> create materialized view mymw refresh complete start with (sysdate) next (add_months(sysdate,1)) with rowid
  as select * from t1 ;

Materialized view created.
```

OR

```
SQL> create materialized view test1.mymw refresh on demand start with (sysdate) next (add_months(sysdate,1)) with rowid
  2  as select * from test1.t1 ;

Materialized view created.
```

As the documentation states

> **START WITH Clause**
>
> Specify a datetime expression for the first automatic refresh time.
>
> **NEXT Clause**
>
> Specify a datetime expression for calculating the interval between
> automatic refreshes.
>
> Both the START WITH and NEXT values must evaluate to a time in the
> future. If you omit the START WITH value, then the database determines
> the first automatic refresh time by evaluating the NEXT expression
> with respect to the creation time of the materialized view. If you
> specify a START WITH value but omit the NEXT value, then the database
> refreshes the materialized view only once. If you omit both the START
> WITH and NEXT values, or if you omit the create_mv_refresh entirely,
> then the database does not automatically refresh the materialized
> view.